# Find the base system, $x$, such that $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\overline{.17}$ are numerals for the same number.

Tags: number-systems

So far I know that $\frac{1}{5} = 0.2$ in base 10. However, I'm not really sure how to convert it into another base. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you know how to write a repeating decimal as a sum?

Answer (score 4):

$0.171717..._x=\dfrac{17_x}{x^2}+\dfrac{17_x}{x^4}+\dfrac{17_x}{x^6}+...$

$=\dfrac{17_x/x^2}{1-1/x^2}=\dfrac{17_x}{x^2-1}=\dfrac{x+7}{x^2-1}=\dfrac15$

Comment: Not OP but do you solve the final quadratic in base $10$? If not, how do you multiply $7$ and $5$

Comment: yes, $5(x+7)=x^2-1\iff x^2-5x-36=0 \iff (x-9)(x+4)=0 \iff x=9 $ or $x=-4$, and take the positive solution

Answer (score 0):

$$(x^2-1)\cdot\dfrac15=(17.17\cdots)_x-(.17\cdots)_x=(17)_x=1\cdot x^1+7$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} (0.1717...)_b =& \left(\frac{1}{b}+\frac{7}{b^2}\right) +
\left(\frac{1}{b^3}+\frac{7}{b^4}\right) + \cdots \\
=& \frac{b+7}{b^2}+\frac{b+7}{b^4} +\cdots \\
=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{b+7}{b^{2n}} \\
=& (b+7)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(b^{-2})^n \\
=& \frac{b+7}{b^2-1}
\end{align}$$
and this is equal to $1/5$, so $b=9$.

Comment: But why don't you convert 1÷5 in base x as 1÷5=0.2=2×x^-1

Comment: But, not your request is find $x$ such that $(0.2)_{10}=(0.1717...)_x$?

Comment: No 0.2 is also in base x.